# PDO Inside a Function

Tags: pdo

I just recently began converting my database queries to PDO. I define $dsn, $opt and $pdo on a separate file that's included in every page on my website. I then have a simple row-count query in another file that displays pages, followed by another file with a more advanced query that extracts a variety of information from multiple tables.

Everything's working up to there.

I also have additional includes with specialty queries, including one that displays "bread crumbs" style navigation links. Every effort I've made to convert it to PDO fails, and my best guess is that the problem relates to the fact that the query is nested inside a function.

Can someone show me how to convert this to PDO?

P.S. I should explain that I use the variables $TopnavName and $TopnavTable because this file is used by several different websites and website sections, each drawing information from a different database table.

---

```
$TopnavName = 'URL';
$TopnavTable = ''.$mysiteid.'_topics'; // (= px_topics in this particular example)

function get_path($node, $TopnavTable, $TopnavName) {
$result = mysql_query('SELECT Parent FROM ' . $TopnavTable . ' WHERE ' . $TopnavName .   '="'.$node.'";');

 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $path = array();
 if ($row['Parent']!='') {
   $path[] = $row['Parent'];

$path = array_merge(get_path($row['Parent'], $TopnavTable, $TopnavName), $path);
}
 return $path;
}

 $mypath = get_path($MyURL, $TopnavTable, $TopnavName);
 $MyLink = $mypath;
 $MyDisplay = $mypath;
 $MyD1 = array('K-2/', '3-5/', '6-8/', '9-12/', '_');
 $MyD2 = array('', '', '', '', ' ');
 $MyDisplay = str_replace($MyD1, $MyD2, $MyDisplay);
 for($i=0;$i<count($mypath);$i++){
 $TopNav = "<a href=\"".$MyLink[$i]."\"> ".$MyDisplay[$i]."</a>&nbsp;&gt;";
 $That = array('<a href="Topics">', '"> ', '&gt;', '<a href="');
 $This = array('<a href="/Topics/">', '">', '&gt; ', '<a href="/Topics/');
 $TopNav = str_replace($That, $This, $TopNav);
 $TopNav = str_replace(''.$MyName.'/', '', $TopNav);
 echo $TopNav;
}
```

Comment: _Every attempt fails_ - how does it fail? What errors do you see?

Comment: If I change the query to this...

    function get_path($node, $TopnavTable, $TopnavName) {
     $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Parent FROM :TNT WHERE :TNN = :Node");
     $stm->execute(array(
        'TNT'=>$TopnavTable,
        'TNN'=>$TopnavName,
        'Node'=>$node
    ));

I get two error messages:

Undefined variable: pdo in
Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

However, I verified that this page includes the file that defines $pdo, so that error makes no sense to me.

Comment: If `$pdo` is defined outside the function it won't be visible inside. Either pass it to your function as an argument, or mark it global inside the function with `global $pdo;`

Comment: (Note: Sorry, I don't know how to format code in comments. Am I missing something, or is that just the way it works?)

Comment: Code in comments isn't really very good for that reason. In any case this additional info should be added to your question since it identifies the problem quite succinctly.

Answer (score 0):

If $pdo is defined outside the function it won't be visible inside. Preferably, pass it to your function as an argument, or mark it global inside the function with

```
global $pdo;
```

Comment: function get_path($node, $TopnavTable, $TopnavName) {
 global $pdo;
 $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Parent FROM :TNT WHERE :TNN = :Node");
 $stm->execute(array(
     'TNT'=>$TopnavTable,
     'TNN'=>$TopnavName,
     'Node'=>$node
));

That nixed both error messages.

Comment: However, I'm now getting this error message:

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''px_topics' WHERE 'URL' = 'Washington/Governor'' at line 1'

(I'm viewing the URL MySite/Topics/Washington/Governor, where Washington/Governor is a value in my database table.)

Comment: I changed the query to  global $pdo;
 $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Parent FROM 'px_topics' WHERE 'Washington/Governor' = :Node");
 $stm->execute(array(
     'Node'=>$node
));

but I get the same error message. So the problem would appear to be $node, and I don't know how to substitute a value for that.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the tips, but this is WAY over my head. PDO is turning into a headache; it just makes everything related to my queries more complex and confusing. Is there some sort of simpler alternative to creating bread crumbs links? One possibility I thought of is to simply create a new field in my database table that contains the bread crumb links; for example, a page at MySite/Topics/Washington/Governor would have the Bread_Crumbs value Topics &gt; Washington &gt; Governor. However, that would be pretty clumsy. Do you know of any better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose something like that could work.

You will have to declare the global `$db` handle to your DB connection.

```
function get_path ($node)
{
    global $db;                        // reference to your PDO DB handle
    global $TopnavTable, $TopnavName;  // and the other globals

    $selector = $db->query(
        "SELECT Parent FROM $TopnavTable WHERE $TopnavName = \"$node\"";');
    $row = $selector->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $path = array();
    if ($row['Parent']!='')
    {
        $path[] = $row['Parent'];

        $path = array_merge (get_path($row['Parent']), $path);
    }
    return $path;
}
```

As the other response suggests, you might want to wrap these globals into some objects, to get a more readable, compact and easy to maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global like others are suggesting, it really isn't that good a plan as far as cleanliness of code. The correct solution for situations like this is a class with static variables for your pdo data.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your `$pdo` to function.Note you cannnot bind table or column names

```
function get_path($pdo,$node,$TopnavTable, $TopnavName) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM $TopnavTable WHERE  $TopnavName = ?");
    $stmt->bindValue(1,$node);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    $row = $stmt->fetch();  
    $path = array_merge(get_path($pdo,$row['Parent'], $TopnavTable, $TopnavName), $path);
    return  $path ;  
}

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
$mypath =  get_path($pdo,$node,$TopnavTable, $TopnavName);
```

I have not tested the recursive call on the function as I haven't got a suitable test table.

You could have a look at **Retrieving a Single Path** in [this](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) article on hierarchical data as a more efficient way of creating your "bread crumbs"

Comment: OK, your script makes the picture much clearer, but I have one question: What's $dbh? I'm guessing it has something to do with my database connection, which is included on another file. Is $dbh another name for $dsn, $opt or $pdo? I don't understand what value it should have.

Comment: Please ignore that last comment. I have it (almost) working now. I'll just have to play with it a little more. I'm marking your comment as the correct answer. Some of the other tips are probably correct, also; they just went a little over my head. ;)